# How to write a recursive function to get the top parent in a tree structure in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have a function that looks like that:

```
private getTopParentNode(rowNode): any {
    if (rowNode.parent == null) {
        return rowNode;
    } else {
        this.getTopParentNode(rowNode.parent);
    }
}
```

I want to return a `rowNode` when it's parent property equals null but it always returns `undefined` instead. As I search for similar problems this function looks good to me. Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: try `rowNode.parent === null`

Comment: you aren't returning in your `else` case. you are just executing the function not returning it's result

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are 100% right. Thank You Sir

Comment: @ggorlen Understood

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Thanks to @TadhgMcDonald

```
private getTopParentNode(rowNode): any {
    let result = null;

    if (rowNode.parent == null) {
        result = rowNode;
    } else {
        result = this.getTopParentNode(rowNode.parent);
    }

    return result;
}
```